# C# Handling Daylight Saving in Time Conversion

Tags: c#, time, dst

I have a date string `2020-11-26T14:24:29-08:00` which is passed to the backend ASP NET MVC application.

I am parsing the date/time string using the below code:

```
    DateTime dateTime = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2020-11-26T14:24:29-08:00", 
                                                  "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzz",
                                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).DateTime;
```

This code is giving me time which is 1 hour less than the actual time. This is because of Daylight Savings.

Now, I want to know if daylight saving is active in the timezone or not. So I wrote the below code:

```
var offset = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2020-11-26T14:24:29-08:00", 
                                       "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzz", 
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

TimeZoneInfo zone = null;
foreach (TimeZoneInfo z in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    if(zone.BaseUtcOffset == offset.Offset)
            zone = z;                        // this runs multiple times   
}
```

The above code `if` condition is hitting multiple times with the following zones satisfying condition.

- Yukon Standard Time
- Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)
- UTC-08
- Pacific Standard Time

So, I further narrowed down the code

```
var offset = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2020-11-26T14:24:29-08:00", 
                                       "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzz", 
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

TimeZoneInfo zone = null;
foreach (TimeZoneInfo z in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    if(zone.BaseUtcOffset == offset.Offset && zone.SupportsDaylightSavingTime)   // added second condition
            zone = z;                        // this runs multiple times   
}
```

This time I got three:

- Yukon Standard Time
- Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)
- Pacific Standard Time

**Is it possible to get the exact timezone? (I know this user is in `Pacific Standard Time`)
Or is it okay to use any (first one) and add one hour to time to get the correct time?**

Comment: Why not use NodaTime to take care of all the conversion details?

Comment: "This code is giving me time which is 1 hour less than the actual time" - that sounds unlikely. The value specifies the offset directly. What *exactly* did you mean by that sentence? What do you mean by "the actual time"? Fundamentally, are you saying you don't trust that the value you've been given correctly represents whatever value was *meant* to be sent?

Comment: @vc74 how will that help ? please enlighten.

Comment: Additionally, if they're really in Pacific Time (and currently observing Pacific Standard Time) then -08:00 is the correct UTC offset, so I don't think any discrepancy *would* be due to DST.

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe I need to check more on this based on your reasoning. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It won't fix your specific issue but I tend to use it as soon as time zones are involved in my code. To answer your question, I don't think there's a way to map an offset to a timezone since multiple timezones following DLS may have exactly the same time at the same instant.

Answer (score 0):

If that datetime string is all you're able to use, I suspect you have to hope the offset they've given you is in line with their time zones daylight savings time (and so could be different for the same location).

I think more information might be needed before a useful answer can be given. Where is this value coming from, what use is the daylight savings time?

Comment: The value is coming from User's Browser Javascript code. Date string is returned by [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback)

Comment: Okay, so I'd bet it will give you the offset that already takes into account daylight saving time. If you need to know specifically whether it's daylight savings or not for some reason, I'd see if you can get the timezone from the calendar and manipulate the UTC time (ending with Z) directly. Don't know how much help that is, hard to know without seeing the full problem.